# OutOfRangeException in php

Tags: php

I get this error

[OutOfRangeException]
  Offset out of range

Though I have used

set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleError'));

in constructor. But the code flow never comes to handleError method and program exits after the error.

Comment: Exceptions are unrelated to the error-handler; see http://php.net/exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `set_error_handler` sets a handler for Errors, not [Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

In user code, errors can be triggered with [trigger_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php), while exception can be thrown with `throw`. The standard library uses a mix of these techniques.

The code you are using is throwing an exception, to stop that ending your program, you need to wrap it in a `try..catch` construct.